# WordPress: add new category when post_save triggered

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I'm new at wordpress plugin development.
I want to add a new category when admin create a new custom post type.
Here is my code:

```
define('POSTTYPE', 'box');
add_action('save_post_' . POSTTYPE, array('controller', 
'add_new_category_when_new_box_created'), 10, 3);

class controller
{
    static function add_new_category_when_new_box_created($post_id, $post, 
$update)
    {
    if (get_post_type() == POSTTYPE) {
        //only new box create category no updated one
        if ($update)
            return false;

        $post_title = $post->post_title;
        wp_create_category($post_title);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
   }
}
```

The problem is, $update is always true even when i create new post.

Comment: what is your taxonomic name.??

Comment: @DevDanidhariya i'm not familiar with taxonomic yet but probably i'm not using it.